# Display array contents in UITextView based on row selection in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm a beginner programmer so I apologize for the basic question. I've done a lot of research and can't find an example that helps me.

I have a simple table that lists cities. When a row is selected, I'd like to display additional information about that city. I have the city data stored in an array.

```
 class TownTableViewController: UITableViewController {

        var towns:[Town] = [
            Town(name: "City1", info: "City1 Info"),
            Town(name: "City2", info: "City2 Info"),
            Town(name: "City3", info: "City3 Info")] ...
```

The UITextView is where I'm having problems. I can't figure out how to display the `town.info(indexPath)` at the selected row. My code is below:

```
import UIKit
class DetailedViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var theTextView:UITextView!
    var town:Town!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //theTextView.text = ("City X Info")
        }

    func textView(textView: UITextView,forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITextView {
        theTextView.text = Town(indexPath).info
    }
```

The line that is commented out had worked to show a single city's information but I don't know how to customize so that each city's information is displayed when the corresponding city is selected in the table.

Thank you in advance for your help!

UPDATE:
I've updated my code per the suggestions below. It is now:

```
import UIKit

class TownTableViewController:  UITableViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!

    var towns:[Town] = [
        Town(name: "City1", info: "City1 Info"),
        Town(name: "City2", info: "City2 Info"),
        Town(name: "City3", info: "City3 Info")]
```

After adding @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView! I connected the tableview with Table View in the TownTableViewController.

The DetailedViewController code is: now

```
import UIKit
class DetailedViewController: UIViewController {
        @IBOutlet weak var theTextView:UITextView!
        var town:Town!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            town[TownTableViewController.indexPathForSeclectedRow()].info
    }
```

I'm still getting the error: 'TownTableviewController.Type' does not have a member named 'indexPathForSelectedRow'.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is indexPathForSelectedRow method

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/indexPathForSelectedRow

```
tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
```

> Return Value An index path identifying the row and section indexes of
>   the selected row, or nil if the index path is invalid.

```
struct Town {
    var name = ""
    var info = ""
}

var towns:[Town] = [
    Town(name: "City1", info: "City1 Info"),
    Town(name: "City2", info: "City2 Info"),
    Town(name: "City3", info: "City3 Info")]

towns[0].name  // "City1"
towns[1].name  // "City2"
towns[2].name  // "City3"

towns[0].info  // "City1 Info"
towns[1].info  // "City2 Info"
towns[2].info  // "City3 Info"

towns[tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()].name
towns[tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()].info
```

You also need an Outlet. Make sure it is connected to your TownTableView

```
class TownTableViewController:  UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
```

Comment: I'm sorry I'm so new at programming in general. How should I implement that my code above since I'm using UITextView?

Comment: towns it is an array just point at your element. towns[tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()]

Comment: Leonardo Savio Dabus, I REALLY appreciate your help! I'm still getting an error. I typed town[TownTableViewController.indexPathForSeclectedRow()].info and xcode says TownTableViewController does not have a member named indexPathForSelectedRow(). It seems like your suggestion should work though.

Comment: If you need further help just let me know

Comment: I added an update to my code above incorporating your suggestions. I'm sorry I'm still having problems. I know this should be very easy! I very much appreciate your help.

Comment: Just zip your project and upload it to Dropbox

Comment: I saw it you need to do it at another VC. You should save your index and or info needed using a top level var. just use load it at the other VC you need that info. Another option is NSUserDefaults to make it available anywhere at your code and also to make it persistent